# POST request is valid (status 200), but fail condition is met

Tags: angularjs, grails

Here is my AngularJS code making the request:

```
$scope.add = function(){    // Function used to add a value to list. Value has name, type, and priority.
    if($scope.thing){
        $scope.items.push(
            {name: $scope.thing,
             type: $scope.worktypeSelection,
             priority: $scope.prioritySelection,
             completed: false,
             comments: '',
             creator: $scope.username,
             assignedTo: $scope.assign
        });

        var itemToJson = $scope.items[$scope.items.length - 1];

        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/server/todoList/addItem', {itemToJson})
        .success(function(response) {alert("success");})
        .error(function(response) {alert("fail");});

        $scope.thing = '';
    }
    else{
        alert("Empty task is not allowed!");
    }
};
```

And my Grails controller:

```
package server

import grails.converters.JSON

class TodoListController {

    def addItem() {
        def newItem = new Item(request.JSON)
        newItem.save(flush: true)
        render newItem as JSON
    }

    def index(){
        render Item.list() as JSON
    }
}
```

And its domain class:

```
package server

class Item {

    String name
    String type
    String priority
    boolean completed = false
    String comments
    String creator
    String assignedTo

    static constraints = {
        name nullable: false
        priority nullable: true
        type nullable: true
        comments nullable: true
        creator nullable: false
        assignedTo nullable: false
    }
}
```

When I initiate the post, I get a 200 from the network (which allegedly means the post is okay), but then I get the fail result (the alert popping up with "fail"). I don't understand what the problem is if the request is in fact reaching the server

Answer (score 0):

the itemToJson is already json object,

dont put in betwwen the "{}"

like this:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/server/todoList/addItem', itemToJson)
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, but this did not fix the problem. Good to know though!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the "then" method, I already had some issues with the error / success method :

```
$http.post( 'url', data ).then(
    function( result ) {
        // success callback
    },
    function( error ) {
        // error callback
    }
);
```

Otherwise, the problem might be that the json returned by the server is incorrect. When the server returns something, the http status code is 200. But that doesn't mean that the data is a well formatted JSON. Check the JSON is correct.

Comment: How can I check the data that is being sent from the server?

Comment: Just print the data before send it, or in your chrome dev tools you can see informations about your HTTP request in the network tab.

Comment: I'm getting "No request data available" on chrome

Comment: Requests are catch by the dev tool only if the panel is opened when the request is sent.

Comment: Would you happen to know what to do with this? it's what I get when I visit addItem and I'm assuming it's the issue:

"Validation Error(s) occurred during save(): - Field error in object 'server.Item' on field 'name': rejected value [null];"

Comment: Yes the data sent seem to have issues. Have you tried to console.log itemToJson before send it ?

Comment: Here is what the console says: http://pastebin.com/fRdH4buL

One problem I notice that might not help now but in the future is that in my grails domain class, type and priority are strings, while they are being passed as objects (How would I declare them as objects in my domain class?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, it seems, had something to do with CORS and my browser. I tried it in IE and it worked fine. After realizing this and wanting to pull my hair out after working on this for hours upon hours, I downloaded [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) for chrome that allows CORS and now it works (more or less, there's some kinks but there is persistence now).